# yii 2.0 dropdownlist don't print sequence number

Tags: drop-down-menu, yii2

I am using dropdownlist in activeform, but i am facing the below issue.

I get the data as an array from the database, but when I display it, even the key value is being displayed. How do I prevent that from happening?

I am getting output as below

```
0
First
1
Second
```

I want the dropdownlist to display just the data and not the key values.

```
First
Second
```

Below is my code:

```php
$query1 = (new Query())->select('model_name')->from('cars');
$data=$query1->all();

<?= $form->field($model, 'dealer')->dropDownlist($data) ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code $data is an array of rows and not strings. Try this:

```php
$data = (new Query())->select('model_name')->from('cars')->column();
```

Doc: [Query::column()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html#column%28%29-detail)